# Manually Process a SOAP/JAX-WS Request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

Is there a way to process SOAP requests manually or on a per-request basis? Due to some very silly technical reasons in an existing system I cannot just publish JAX-WS services to an Endpoint created via the standard Endpoints factory. My situation is a bit messed up in that I am basically handed a raw InputStream from a ServerSocket and told to process it.

The data in the stream is being sent from a client that makes SOAP requests. The developer of the client provides a bunch of WSDL's and XSD's for generating the necessary server side classes using wsimport and xjc. All of it is JAX-WS and I would like to leverage as much of JAX-WS as possible to minimize the work I have to do.

Does anyone know where to start looking for how to do this? Is it even possible? My best guess at the moment is that I have to manually implement customer Endpoint or Provider.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory`?

Comment: You can use [this tutorial](http://www.omii.ac.uk/wiki/JaxWsTutorial#section-JaxWsTutorial-6.3.Workarounds). I'm linking it to the `Stream` usage to get web service results.

Comment: Axis2 provides a [handler for a TCP endpoint](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/transport_howto.html). If you can get that working you can leverage the rest of the Axis stack rather than rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process the raw input with the following steps. Just parse the incoming message as you would any XML stream

```
     try{ //throws a bunch of XML parsing related exceptions
      XMLInputFactory xFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
      XMLStreamReader xStream = xFactory.createXMLStreamReader(req.getInputStream());
      //Start skipping tags til you get to the message payload
      for(int nodeCount=0; nodeCount < 3; nodeCount++){
             xStream.nextTag(); //Jump <Envelope/>,<Body/>,<theMessageNode/>   
          }
      //You're now at the level of the actual class; Now unmarshal the payload  

      JAXBContext ctxt  = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourResponseClass.class);
      Unmarshaller um = ctxt.createUnmarshaller();
      JAXBElement<YourResponseClass.class> elem = um.unmarshal(xStream, YourResponseClass.class);             
      YourResponseClass theObj = elem.getValue();

     }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }
```

Comment: what if there will be commentary between envelope and body :) will your magic number 3 still work?

Comment: @JIV, no this doesn't prepare for that. The keyword in this question is **Manually**. So if comments are going to be sent in the requests, it must've been previously agreed on to facilitate the manual processing. Besides, I don't see the point in adding comments to a SOAP request. A wsdl? yes :)

Comment: Great minds think alike? This is actually the stop-gap solution I came up with last night. I'd still like to find a way to avoid having to do this though since there are quite a few services to dupe and objects to marshal/unmarshal.

Comment: @KingPhilroy, ultimately, the cleanest option is to rebuild an http request from the raw bytes you're being fed. Take the reconstructed payload (really all you'll need to do extra, is set http headers) and feed it to a proper JAX-WS service on the designated port. In theory, it should just take it like a regular soap request. So set this mechanism up as a proxy or something to all the services that require duplication, for forwarding to an actual webservice